# show only single record from multiple array values

Tags: php, jquery

I am fetching data from an `api` and i need to fetch data for same value only once.for ex. "`Test Storage`" is coming 3 times and i need to show it only first record of it and same for walk top and walk middle.This is format of xml array

I am fetching data

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [R_Code] => 1
    [sTypeName] => Test Storage
    [iDefLeaseNum] => 1

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [R_Code] => 1
    [sTypeName] => Test Storage
    [iDefLeaseNum] => 2
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [R_Code] => 1
    [sTypeName] => Test Storage
    [iDefLeaseNum] => 1
)SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [R_Code] => 1
    [sTypeName] => Walk Middle
    [iDefLeaseNum] => 1
)SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [R_Code] => 1
    [sTypeName] => Walk Top
    [iDefLeaseNum] => 1
)SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [R_Code] => 1
    [sTypeName] => Walk Top
    [iDefLeaseNum] => 1
)SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [R_Code] => 1
    [sTypeName] => Walk Middle
    [iDefLeaseNum] => 1
)



  foreach($formatUnits->NewDataSet->Table as $unit)
   {
    echo $unit->iDefLeaseNum;
    echo $unit->sTypeName;
   }
```

Comment: please show relevant code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the value and check if it exists before outputting it.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($formatUnits->NewDataSet->Table as $unit){
    if(! isset($arr[$unit->sTypeName]) ){
        $arr[$unit->sTypeName] = $unit->iDefLeaseNum;
        echo $unit->iDefLeaseNum;
        echo $unit->sTypeName;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is showing error   Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in this line    if(! isset($arr[$unit->sTypeName]) ){

Comment: @phpdeveloper try to var_dump to get the type of the **$unit->sTypeName**

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working now. I used  trim($arr[$utype] = trim($dclength))

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `array_unique()` function to remove duplicate elements from array.

Check out this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php